# Convert THREE.hs Units to Real World Feet

Tags: 3d, three.js, augmented-reality

I realize the units in three.js are whatever you want them to be. As long as things are sized accordingly to one another 1 unit can equal 1ft or 1mile etc.

However, I'm building an augmented reality app that I want to be able to place objects in my scene to scale with the real world. For example, say I want to place 1ft diameter pole that's 20ft high in the scene. I want the pole to appear as if it's actually 1ft in diameter and 20ft tall in the realworld.

I'm stumped as to how to go about figuring out exactly how many units are needed to make something appear 1ft in the real world.

Any ideas on how I could go about figuring this out would be more than appreciated!

Comment: Just like you said they're whatever units you want. If you decide 1 unit = 1 inch. then make your 1ft pole's diameter 12 for 12 inches and it's height 12*20 for 20ft. If you decide 1 unit = 1ft then make the diameter 1 and the height 12. If you decide 1 unit = 1 meter than to get a 1ft diameter make the diameter 0.3048 and for 20ft height make the height 6.096 meters.

Comment: The problem becomes making it look like the actual size in the realworld. Imagine having the camera view on screen and you're looking at a power pole. Now imagine I place a pole right next to it with webgl using my coordinates and the coordinates of the pole. I need the augmented pole to appear identical in size to the real thing. I guess I can just do trial and error until I determine how many units work to equal 1ft. I was hoping for some sort of scientific approach to figuring it out if possible.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to get a specific scale without using some kind of physical token in your environment that your camera can read as use as a scaling reference. Many applications use QR codes for this function. But keep in mind that it should be a known and reproducible size. A business card sized token may show a car model at 1:32 scale. But scale that token up to poster size, and you may see a 1:1 scale car instead.

Comment: Thanks TheJim01. I would love to use the token solution, but it in this scenario it won't work. Ive seen those tokens before and they work well for some scenarios. I'm pulling assets that are geolocated and placing a large number of objects in the scene in my app. I've got my coordinates (external gps with <1ft accuracy) and then placing objects in the scene based on their coordinates in reference to my location.